# IE Compatibility Problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I cannot seem to get the border around the title and elephant elements to go away in IE. Seems to work fine in chrome and Firefox. Does anyone understand why? Reasoning and answer would be much more helpful instead of just an answer. I also cannot get the borders of the elements to work in IE, however that is not as important to me right now.  Thanks in advance.

[**Link to website**](http://stockinput.com/index.html)

Comment: you should post your code or a link to a demo.  http://jsfiddle.net will work as well.

Comment: "elephant elements"? Wha...?

Comment: im sorry forgot to add link hahaha. Yeah elephants do love them borders.

Comment: Please post the code in your question

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo I have added a link to the website. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE follows the web browser tradition of drawing a colored border around an image that is a link (technically, an `img` element inside an `a` element that has the `href` attribute). This was meant to make the user notice that the image is a link.

To remove the border, use the attribute `border=0` in the `img` tag or use a corresponding CSS rule, like `img { border: none }`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.